# Svelte Darkmode Button needs to be clicked twice

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I am currently working my way into Svelte. This is my first framework after learning HTML, CSS and JS.

I would like to switch between a dark and light mode. For that I followed this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OyjZ7dezADw

The only difference is that I use standard material icons.

The problem is that after the page has loaded I have to press the dark mode button twice to change the icon. The problem was also described in the video and fixed with onMount, but this fix did not work for me.

I have tried many things, but the variable darkTheme is always undefined when the DOM is created.

Does anyone happen to have a tip for a beginner?

__layout.svelte:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import TopAppBar, {
    Row,
    Section,
    Title,
    AutoAdjust,
  } from "@smui/top-app-bar";
  import IconButton from "@smui/icon-button";

  let topAppBar: TopAppBar;

  let darkTheme: boolean | undefined = undefined;

  onMount(() => {
    darkTheme = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;
    darkTheme = darkTheme;
  });
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <!-- Dark and Lightmode CSS change-->
  <!-- SMUI Styles -->
  {#if darkTheme === undefined}
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="/smui.css"
      media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="/smui-dark.css"
      media="screen and (prefers-color-scheme: dark)"
    />
  {:else if darkTheme}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/smui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/smui-dark.css" media="screen" />
  {:else}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/smui.css" />{/if}
</svelte:head>

<!--TopAppBar-->
<TopAppBar bind:this={topAppBar} variant="fixed" color="primary">
  <Row>
    <Section>
      <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
        <!--Darkmode Button-->
        <IconButton
          on:click={() => (darkTheme = !darkTheme)}
          class="material-icons"
          aria-label="Darkmode"
          >{darkTheme ? "light_mode" : "dark_mode"}</IconButton
        >
      </div>
      <Title>Test</Title>
    </Section>
    <Section align="end" toolbar>
      <IconButton class="material-icons" aria-label="calendar"
        >calendar_month</IconButton
      >
      <IconButton class="material-icons" aria-label="books"
        >menu_book</IconButton
      >
      <IconButton class="material-icons" aria-label="profile"
        >account_circle</IconButton
      >
    </Section>
  </Row>
</TopAppBar>
<AutoAdjust {topAppBar}>
  <slot />
</AutoAdjust>

<style>
  :global(.mdc-)

  /* Hide everything above this component. */
  :global(#smui-app),
  :global(body),
  :global(html) {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
    position: static !important;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could initialize the `darkTheme` variable with `true`/ `false` instead of `undefined`
2. Additionally, try to use `beforeUpdate` lifecycle event (*runs immediately before the DOM is updated*) instead to set your `onMount` (*runs after the component is first rendered to the DOM*). I'm not sure if this is good practice though.
3. Also try using the reactive `$:` variable for `darkTheme` like this
   $: darkTheme = true // false // undefined